# How can I know it is an extremum in a zone in which the derivative is not defined?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Find extremum points of $g(x)=x(x-1)^{1\over 3}$, $x\in \Bbb{R}$.

What I did is: $g'(x)=(x-1)^{1\over 3}+x{1\over 3}(x-1)^{-{2\over 3}}=(x-1)^{-{2\over 3}}\left((x-1)+x{1\over 3}\right)=(x-1)^{-{2\over 3}}\left({4\over 3}x-1\right)$. $g'(1)=0$. For $x={3\over 4}$, ${4\over 3}x-1=0$, but $(x-1)^{-{2\over 3}}$ is not define. So is it a potential extremum or not at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Point $x= 1$ is not an extremum since it holds $lim_{x \rightarrow 1} g'(x) = \infty$. The only extremum lies at $x = \frac{3}{4}$.

Comment: I firstly talk about extremum suspect. As I said, $x=1$ is clearly a suspect, but I couldn't tell whether or not $x={3\over 4}$ because the derivative is not defined in that point.

Comment: $g'(\frac{3}{4})=0, g'(1) = (1-1)^{-2/3}(4/3-1) = \frac{1}{3}* 0^{- \frac{2}{3}} = \infty$.

Comment: $g'({3\over 4})=(-{1\over 4})^{-{2\over 3}}*0$=ERROR 

(-{1\over 4})^{-{2\over 3}} is not defined

Comment: $(-{1\over 4})^{-{2\over 3}}$ is not defined **

Comment: @MeitarAbarbanel: Why not? By both theory and my TI-Nspire calculator I get $\left(-\frac 14\right)^{-2/3}=\sqrt[3]{16}\approx 2.51984209979$.